# Minimize and maximize buttons missing only for certain programs in Pop! OS

Tags: x11, gnome, desktop-environment, pop-os

Unfortunately, for some but not all programs (Thunderbird, Signal, Libre Office, QGIS) the minimize and maximize were suddenly missing and appear maximized (not full screen. I noticed it suddenly without having installed anything previously). All other programs appear with minimize and maximize buttons.

Since, I have updated my Pop! OS (to Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS) and tried reinstalling the programs as well as changing the settings in GNOME 3, but without any success. Especially for QGIS without the buttons I cannot move the different window of the program and thus can hardly use it.

Answer (score 1):

Run `gnome-tweaks` and click on the "Window Titlebars" menu-entry.  There should be an option for you to enable "Maximize" and "Minimize" buttons".

[image]

These are disabled by default.  The combination of Workspaces and using the "Activities" layout to switch between windows is used by many instead of the old-style "minimize to the taskbar".

I suspect some programs still have the minimize and maximize buttons because they draw their own title-bars and don't check system settings.  I can confirm that chromium and MS Teams behave like that.

Comment: Thank you. I have the Minimize and maximize buttons enabled in gnome tweaks, which is why they appear in all other programs and even in the settings etc., but even with the buttons enabled in gnome-tweaks, they don't appear in the mentioned programs.